# Installing Tensorflow on Amazon EC2 Free Tier for testing

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, tensorflow

I used [The Tensorflow for Poets](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/#0) tutorial to train a model for classifying some images. Now I want to use that in a webpage on an EC2 instance on AWS Free Tier. As stated in the tutorial it is as simple as running this simple command:

```
python -m scripts.label_image --graph=tf_files/retrained_graph.pb --image=
```

I'm not planning to test many images all at once.

But to be able to do this I need to install Tensorflow on my EC2 instance. I was wondering if it is possible to do that and stay in the free zone? And I would appreciate a good tutorial for a beginner on how to do that.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Answering your question: Yes, it should be possible to install Tensforflow in a EC2 instance. However, asking for tutorial recommendations is considered off-topic. See the "What topics can I ask about here?" link in the comment above.

Answer (score 0):

The free tier EC2 does not worry about what the instance is use for.

Rather, how long it's instances are running for.

A t2.micro you will get 750hours a month.

All "free-tier eligible" products are labelled appropriately..

If you need to use data storage and database they also have free tier deals available.

You can setup cloud watch monitoring to alert you of charges etc. To keep you informed.

AWS support are very helpful.

https://aws.amazon.com/free/

Personally I am fan of the free tier Ubuntu amd64 instance.

Thus the instructions for tensorflow are here.

https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux